# How to prevent html code appearing above python great_tables in quarto gfm reports?

Tags: python, quarto

When I render a gfm report from Quarto and push to github, the gfm report displays a massive amount of html above the great_tables table. How can I prevent this?

[image]

````
---
title: 'HTML junk'
author: 'Joseph Powers'
date: 2024-03-14
format: gfm
---

```{python}
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from great_tables import GT
```

```{python}
N = int(5e3)
TRIALS = int(1)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": np.random.binomial(TRIALS,  0.65, N),
        "B": np.random.binomial(TRIALS,  0.65, N),
        "C": np.random.binomial(TRIALS,  0.65, N),
        "D": np.random.binomial(TRIALS,  0.67, N)
    }
)
```

## No html, but an ugly table ...
```{python}
print(df.head().to_markdown())
```

## great_tables
```{python}
GT(df.head())
```
````